# Update multiple values from array of objects in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have an array of objects like

```
[
  {id:1, value:'a'},
  {id:2, value:'b'},
  {id:3, value:'c'},
  {id:4, value:'d'},
  {id:5, value:'e'}
]
```

I want to updateMany in a single query like update according to the object value i-e
id 1 will have value a,id 2 will have value b etc

Comment: You can try using the `Bulk` write method.

Comment: Is this a sub-array in a single document or are the objects in the sample several documents in a collection?

Comment: a single one . In short i want to set dynamic value for every object accordingly in a single query